# How to fix EntityValidationError on new user registration?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I created a new project with individual user accounts and added 2 properties (Display Name and Username(in code DisplayName/LoginUsername)), while DisplayName didn't give me any problems, LoginUsername was apparently a problem for the program.

I've tried to add it to migration, I tried to do it without LoginUsername which worked but is not what I intended and I've tried searching online to no avail.

The part with the Error is

```
        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.LoginUsername, Email = model.Email, DisplayName = model.DisplayName };
                var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                AddErrors(result);
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

My RegisterViewModel includes

```
    public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Display name")]
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string LoginUsername { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

I don't which information is still missing, please tell me what else is necessary to add here.

What I wanted was for the registration to include an actual username instead of just the Email, which would also be used for login. Instead I got the error message.

Help would be greatly appreciated. :)

SOLVED: I didn't use the standard UserName provided by IdentityFramework and the app couldn't fill both username props with data, but since they were both required it was unable to save the account. So I accidentally made a unnecessary second property.

Comment: _“LoginUsername was apparently a problem for the program”_ – But what does the error say? The result from `UserManager.CreateAsync` should give you some details on what is going wrong. The user name is used as a primary identifier of the user, so there are some restrictions on it that could cause a problem here. The error message should give you details on that.

Comment: System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

Comment: The line that was marked as the source of the problem was: var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Comment: Yes, check that `EntityValidationErrors` property. Debug your application to look at the exception with your debugger.